# SSL Certificate Issue on android

Tags: android, ios

I have done ssl-offloading on the VIP. After that my app working fine in iOS Device but not working android devices. After that i re-install  ssl certificate. Its working android devices. I found some intermediate and root certificate missed. My question is how it works iOS with out intermediate and root certificate.

Comment: I think it depends on Android\iOS version at least

Comment: why did you tag android